# Unable to launch apps on Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 5

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I've installed Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 5, but I'm unable to launch apps, such as the browser. Does anyone know a fix? I installed via the AUR versions of `ubuntu-device-flash` and `phablet-tools`.

Answer (score 0):

So far I know there are different images for nexus 5. If you installed a 16.04 one, that might be buggy because it's in development. Try to find and install a 15.04 one. That can work better.